# Taking user input to list directory with shell script

Tags: list, shell, unix, directory

I've written a little script that will ask for a directory and then list the directories within that directory, only it always tells me that there is no such directory. Where might I have gone wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a directory to list"
read answer
ls -d $answer
```

Comment: Wrap $answer: `"$answer"`

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

Your problem is likely one or more of the following:

1. You aren't quoting your directory name properly.
2. The `-d` flag will only list the directory itself.
3. You may be passing the name of a directory that doesn't exist.

### Solution

Assuming you're using Bash, you can do this much more simply. For example:

```
read -p 'Enter a directory to list: '
ls "$REPLY"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find to get a listing of directories, and you need to quote the answer if you are expecting spaces within the path:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a directory to list"
read answer
find "$answer" -type d
```